# How to handle a situation where 90% of the value on a dependent variable are zero?

Tags: multiple-regression, linear

I have a data set with numeric variable. I am trying to fit a regression model on my data. But the outcome variable are 90% zero. Is it appropriate to still fit a multiple regression in this case?
 Thanks

Comment: the variable contains counts or is a continuous variable?

Comment: If your DV contains counts, a [tag:zero-inflation] model may be appropriate. Do the zeros and the non-zeros come from different data generating processes? If so, some kind of mixture model may be appropriate. And what are you interested in? Please edit your question to add more background info; as it stands, we likely can't help you.

Comment: @rapaio The variable is a continuous variable.

Answer (score 0):

It probably depends on a couple things:

1. Total sample size. If you have 1000 observations that are not zero, you can probably still run the regression and get some results.
2. What type of numeric variable your response is. Is it a continuous, or a count variable? If it is a count variable, you can probably do either a zero-inflated negative binomial or zero-inflated poisson regression.